# Calling fancybox via ajax - where to put options?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, fancybox

I'm calling a fancybox-site-preview via ajax and don't know where to put further fancybox options.

```
$.ajax({
    type    : "POST",
    cache   : false,
    url     : "../mysite/",
    data    : $('#myform').serializeArray(),
    success : function(data) {
        $.fancybox(data);
        }
    });
```

I'd like to add `width: '100%', height: '100%',`
I tried it with various positions in, before, and after the `$.fancybox(data);` but I didn't get it to work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I can answer and solve my own questions: All the solutions seem to work, but you have to define `minWidth` and `minHeight`. It doesn't work with `width` and `height`.

Comment: your question wasn't about `width` and `height` options not working but where to put those options. your question was misleading and your answer doesn't solve the questions asked.

Comment: ... and actually just setting `autoSize : false` would have been enough without `minWidth` and `minHeight`

Comment: Hm, I thouht my problem was, where to put the options. But it wasn't, as I realized LATER.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax: {
    type     : "POST",
    cache    : false,
     url : "../mysite/",
     data : $('#myform').serializeArray(),
    success: function(data) {
        $.fancybox({
            'width': 100,
            'height': 100,
            'enableEscapeButton' : false,
            'overlayShow' : true,
            'overlayOpacity' : 0,
            'hideOnOverlayClick' : false,
            'content' : data
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am afraid that `'width': 100` will return a `100px` width box ;)

Comment: You should use width:auto instead of using width:100%  , besides this did ur problem solved ?

Answer (score 1):

```
function (data) {
   $.extend(data, {'width': '100%', 'height': '100%'});
   $.fancybox(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url: "../mysite/",
    data: $('#myform').serializeArray(),
    success: function(data) {
        $.fancybox(data, {
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "100%"
        });
    }
});​
```

Comment: @maxcode : this does actually work, but if you want 100% size then you need to set `autoSize : false`